# Write Timeout while writing bytes to web socket in apache tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, java-websocket

I have Java web socket web application. The websocket endpoint interacts with mobile clients. In one of the use case, the web application needs to write bytes of the size of 10MB or more to the web-socket outputstream. Following is the code which writes to the output stream :

```
     if (webSocSession.isOpen()) {
          webSocSession.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(byteBuffer);
          byteBuffer.clear();
        }
```

I am getting the following exception at times when the writing to the web-socket :

```
IOException writing to web-socket
java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Write timeout
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:324)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:259)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendBytes(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:131)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendBinary(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:43)
at test.web.websocket.LIMSEndpoint$SocketWorker.writeToWebSocket(LIMSEndpoint.java:1188)
at test.web.websocket.LIMSEndpoint$SocketWorker.run(LIMSEndpoint.java:1127)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Write timeout
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.vectoredOperation(SocketWrapperBase.java:1458)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:1376)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:1347)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:93)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:509)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:311)
```

I tried setting the up the following SEND timeout property to 0 ( infinite write timeout ) , but it does not help. The following Apache Tomcat doc helped - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/web-socket-howto.html

```
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT
```

The web socket session max idle timeout has been set to 0 ( not to timeout )

```
Session.setMaxIdleTimeout(0)
```

Any help in this regard will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the clients receive buffer is filled up and it cuts the connection. I know this will happen the other way around, when a client sends large data to an apache server and the server isn't configured to have an extended binary buffer. See:  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.binaryBufferSize

Perhaps you can get around the problem by sending the data in smaller chunks, sendBytes have a partial version.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/websocketapi/index.html?jakarta/websocket/Session.html

Comment: Thanks ton. Will test your suggestion and update

Answer (score 0):

See this similar SO question: [How can you set org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482114/how-can-you-set-org-apache-tomcat-websocket-blocking-send-timeout) - setting/overriding `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT` has to be done in a very specific way in order to be picked up.

Also, as you are sending large messages, you probably also need to override the following properties on `WebSocketTransportRegistration` :

```
        registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(10 * 1024 * 1024);
        registration.setSendTimeLimit(120_000);
```