# How can you set org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, websocket

What's the expected way to set org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT to increase a tomcat websocket timeout? Tomcat documentation states the following:

> This may be changed by setting the property
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT in the user
> properties collection attached to the WebSocket session.

The WebSocketSession I see available in the TextWebSocketHandler's afterConnectionEstablished method doesn't apear to have user properties. So, I assume that's not what the documentation means. In looking at TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy, it appears to me that it never looks at an endpoint user properties. It also doesn't appear to me that you can overwrite TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy since AbstractHandshakeHandler has a hardcoded class name for TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT` is an user property you need to set on WebSocket API's [`Session`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/websocketapi/javax/websocket/Session.html), not the Spring abstractions of this interface.

You can configure it in the `afterConnectionEstablished` method by casting the Spring `WebSocketSession` to `NativeWebSocketSession` and retrieving the underlying WebSocket API session:

```java
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
    if (session instanceof NativeWebSocketSession) {
        final Session nativeSession = ((NativeWebSocketSession) session).getNativeSession(Session.class);
        if (nativeSession != null) {
            nativeSession.getUserProperties()
                         .put("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT", 60_000L);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very glad I came across this page! We were having issues with load tests sending 1000s of messages, only about half were being received, and it proved extremely difficult to track down the cause. Although the solution posted isn't quite right, at least for our codebase, it very much pointed me in the right direction.
For reference, I had to subclass `SubProtocolWebSocketHandler` and override the `afterConnectionEstablished()` method as suggested above, but the `Session` is `StandardWebSocketSession` not `NativeWebSocketSession`.

```
    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(final WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        final Session nativeSession = ((StandardWebSocketSession) session).getNativeSession(Session.class);
        nativeSession.getUserProperties()
            .put("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT", CUSTOM_BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT);
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }
```

Then, in the relevant `@Configuration` class where `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` is specified, provide a `@Bean` `@Primary` method to create an instance of it, that overrides the default `SubProtocolWebSocketHandler` bean.